# Filter cell array by some string value

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array, something like this:

```
A = 

    '5523'    '2012-10-26'    '23'    'T'    '17.7'
    '5513'    '2012-10-26'    '23'    'T'    '22.1'
    '5506'    '2012-10-26'    '23'    'C'    '16.2'
```

Now I would like to filter all records that have `T`. So I would like to get this array:

```
A = 

    '5523'    '2012-10-26'    '23'    'T'    '17.7'
    '5513'    '2012-10-26'    '23'    'T'    '22.1'
```

I could parse all array, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner to do it:

```
A = A(strcmp(A(:,4), 'T'), :);
```

The inner part, `strcmp(A(:,4), 'T')`, is comparing column 4 of all rows to `'T'`. Then that boolean vector can extract matching rows from `A` with logical indexing.

Comment: @llnk I know what you mean. But once you get used to logical indexing and matrix operations, "classic programming" seems very verbose and can be quite frustrating!

Comment: @llnk MATLAB is more oriented toward functional programming and favors vector operations. It looks very elegant once you get used to it.